# Creating a pop up menu within a page called by ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I've been trying to create a button within a php page called by ajax function that pops up a menu when clicked for quite some time but I can't seem to figure it out. The php page is posted under a div called cbox through an ajax method named postAll:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleElement(id) 
{
    var element=document.getElementById(id);
    if(element.style.display=="block")
    {
        element.style.display="none";
    }
    else
    {
        element.style.display="block";
    }
}
function postAll()
{
    if(String(window.location).indexOf("?")==-1)
    {
        var location=window.location.href;
    }
    else
    {
        var location=window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.indexOf("?"));
        var clength=(window.location.href.length-1)-(window.location.href.indexOf("currentpage"))-11;
        var currentpage=window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.length-clength,clength);
    }
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("cbox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","dynamic.php?location="+location+"&currentpage="+currentpage,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    document.getElementById("option").addEventListener("click",function(){alert("Success");});
    postAll();
});
</script>
```

I've tried using addEventListener but I'm not sure I'm using that correctly. I've also tried using the following code but it didn't work either:

```
$("#cbox").delegate("a","click", function() {
   toggleElement('option_toggle');
});
$("#cbox").on("click", "a", function() {
   toggleElement('option_toggle');
});
```

For the .on method I got an uncaught type error as well. 
Here's the actual button I'm trying to get to pop up a menu:

```
<div id="option"><p><a href="#"><img class="select" src="cog.png"></img></a></p></div>
<div id="option_toggle" style="display:none;"> Random Text </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: jquery has a ajax framework that will make all your ajax requests a lot simplier.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is a piece of gold!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the code to open a dialog in your sample. 
Anyway - I added a really small example.
For this code, I download [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/download) and I followed the sample for [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

I even added Ajax, even though there is no connection, and I wrote everything with JQuery - as a response to the comments you got.

Here is file #1 - contains a button that invokes an Ajax call to some more content

```
<button onclick="loadAjaxContent()">Load ajax content</button>


<div id="ajaxContentContainer">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadAjaxContent()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/Application/content',
            data:{param1:"value1"},
            success:function(result){$("#ajaxContentContainer").html(result)},
            error:function(result){$("#ajaxContentContainer").html(result.responseText)}

        })
    }
</script>
```

Now here is page #2 - which is injected into the first one. This page has another button that opens a dialog.

```
<button onclick="openPopup()">open popup</button>


<div id="dialogContent">
    this is a dialog content
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dialogContent").dialog({autoOpen:false});
    function openPopup()
    {

       $("#dialogContent").dialog('open');
    }
</script>
```

Please make sure you import all the js and css files correctly. The list of files to be imported is :

1. jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css (version may vary) - this file should have an "images" folder right next to it
2. jquery-1.6.2.min.js (version may vary)
3. jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js (version may vary)

You must import the "jquery-ui" file AFTER the "jquery" file. The order is important.

This should work, or at least give you a good kick start. 
Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't want a button to load the initial content from the php page. I have that loaded automatically with an ajax call. The button itself is within the ajax call, and I've been having trouble getting onclick functioning within an ajax call. I've read somewhere javascript isn't processed within ajax.

Comment: Though I did replace all the xml statements with the ajax method and that works fine now, so thanks for that.

Comment: I got it working finally. I changed some things around. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you are right saying that javascript is not processed within ajax. but it is processed one I do $("..").html(result). - that is if the ajax returned HTML. but if it returns JavaScript - you can run "eval" on it.